# Cannot run basic example autoit script

Tags: autoit

I have compiled below script with AutoIt and the .exe file is created. However, when I run it won't start (just flash up a sec in right bottom screen and then disappears). Any idea why?

Script example copied from: [AutoIt General Help and Support Forum](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/98253-anyone-got-an-example-of-controlclick-working-in-iehidden/)

```
#include <IE.au3>

Opt("MouseCoordMode", 2)
Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 4)

$hWnd = WinGetHandle("AutoIt Script Home Page - Windows Internet Explorer")

;WinWait($hWnd)
;If Not WinActive($hWnd) Then WinActivate($hWnd)
;WinWaitActive($hWnd)

; WINDOW IS NOT ACTIVE!!

sleep(1000)
ControlClick($hWnd, "", "Internet Explorer_Server1", "left", 1, 722, 125) ;;;;Opens The forum

; Does not Work when NOT active!!

;even statusbar only works when active

$status=StatusbarGetText($hWnd)
ConsoleWrite($status&@LF)
```

Comment: what value has `$hWnd`?

Comment: Please provide information about your AutoIt version by `ConsoleWrite( @AutoItVersion & '|' & @AutoItX64 & @CRLF )` and the site which you want to test with the example script.